# Pass image back from a pushed view controller and display image on original VC

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates, protocols

I've been through several examples of passing data between view controllers using prepare for segue, as well as protocol/delegate methods... to no avail, I'm still stuck with my project and could use some help.

I'm trying to 1) select an image from VC1, 2) edit the image on VC2, and 3) pass the edited image back to VC1 and display it.

I'm stuck on the pass back and display part.. all help is much appreciated!

I have a HomeViewController (VC1) from which I use UIImagePicker to select an image, then view/edit that image on another view controller (VC2) that I push onto the stack in didFinishPicking... as shown below:

```
extension HomeViewController : UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        let selectImageandCaptionVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SelectImageandCaption") as? SelectImageandCaption

        selectImageandCaptionVC?.image = image

        picker.pushViewController(selectImageandCaptionVC!, animated: true)

    }
  }
}
```

On VC2 I edit the image, then I'm attempting to pass back the edited image, and display it on VC1. Here's my code on VC2:

```
import UIKit

// protocol used for sending data back to HomeViewController
protocol ImageAndCaptionDelegate: class {
func userDidEnterInformation(image: UIImage)
}


class SelectImageandCaption: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

weak var delegate: ImageAndCaptionDelegate? = nil

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var imageWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!


var image : UIImage = UIImage()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollView.delegate = self
    imageView.image = image
}


@IBAction func doneButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    //Code that edits image
     let croppedImage = UIImage(cgImage: croppedCGImage!)

    //Pass image pack to HomeViewController
    delegate?.userDidEnterInformation(image: croppedImage)

    // Attempts to go back to the previous view controller and show croppedImage...

    //let HomeViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as? HomeViewController
    //self.navigationController?.pushViewController(HomeViewController!, animated: true)
    //self.navigationController?.popToViewController(HomeViewController!, animated: true)
    //present(HomeViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

 }
}
```

Back on VC1 Here is my code for the cropped image to get passed back

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, ImageAndCaptionDelegate {

var image : UIImage = UIImage()
var video : AVAsset?
@IBOutlet weak var step1Image: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var step1ProgressImage: UIImageView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

func userDidEnterInformation(image: UIImage) {
    self.step1Image.image = image
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the delegate

```
let selectImageandCaptionVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SelectImageandCaption") as! SelectImageandCaption
selectImageandCaptionVC.image = image
selectImageandCaptionVC.delegate = self
self.present(selectImageandCaptionVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that! Thanks for the help, this was my issue.